# How to cluster points (coordinates in a large data set

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, coordinates

I have a large data set made of x and y coordinates (no necessarily lat, lng). Points are not ordered.

```
df <- data.frame(point=1:7, x=c(3,7,2,23,5,67,16) , y=c(1,4,5,23,17,89,20))
>df
point x  y
1    3  1
2    7  4
3    2  5
4    23 23
5    5  17
6    67 89
7    16 20
```

Is there an easy way to cluster points? (according to a radius for example)

So for example:

points 1, 2, 3 would be together - group A

points 4, 5, 7 would be together - group B

point 6 would be group C

I have tried to use: %>% arrange to sort values, and then x-(x+1) (coordinate differences)
but the method is not perfect and there are situations where clustering isn't done properly.

Any suggestions or comments!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try `hclust` with  `cutree`.

```
df$group <- cutree(hclust(dist(df[,2:3])), 3)
df
#  point  x  y group
#1     1  3  1     1
#2     2  7  4     1
#3     3  2  5     1
#4     4 23 23     2
#5     5  5 17     1
#6     6 67 89     3
#7     7 16 20     2
```